# java.lang.RuntimeException: Need to install JAI Image I/O package

Tags: java, jboss

So I received this error when I ran Tesseract. First of all, I've read many questions on stackoverflow that my file is corrupted or unreadable. I did not get error saying that Image/PDF is unsupported. The files are reading properly by java.io.File.

This error is thrown when I run this code:
`ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();`

This error appears when I exported my project into a WAR file and deployed into JBOSS server. It doesn't throw error while running locally. I'm suspecting that the JAI Image I/O library is missing from the WAR file. Is there something I'm missing on the JBOSS side, like adding a java build path or setting the referenced libraries?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm suspecting that the JAI Image I/O library is missing from the WAR file.

It is missing from the JRE installation in the target host. It should be in `lib/ext`.